# How to integrate spring context of library to application context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've written library that use some spring and hibernate beans. For example it uses SessionFactory. In my library i configure spring context in xml file.

I want to do next thing:
Clients of my library add maven dependency to their project and in the time of their application starting my library uses common spring context of application.

I know about spring.pactories in Spring boot. But i'm not sure about existing auto-configuration in "pure" spring.

In the perfect situation i would like to remove spring-context dependency form my lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option if your library has context configuration class or xml file user can add it to his configuration by specifying it in the `@Import` annotation.

I would recommend you create java configuration class which will import your `xml` configuration and then user would need to just add `@Import` annotation to his code, specifying your configuration class as an argument.

I am not aware about if you can do it another way without using `spring-boot`.

Documentation about `@Import` annotation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html

Regarding `spring-context` dependency you can just make it `provided`, because to use your library your user anyway will need this dependency.